# Plotting partial effects with confidence intervals for lmer models

Tags: r, effects, lme4

I would like to plot the partial effects of the terms in my model.

I used the `effects` package which is supposed to work on `lmer` models, however I get an error related to the class of the model object.

The following is a reproducible example:

```
library(lme4)
library(effects)

fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy) #sleepstudy is an example dataset in lme4   

plot(effect("Days", fm1))
# Error in plot(effect("Days", fm1)) : 
#   error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': Error in # UseMethod("effect", mod) : 
#  no applicable method for 'effect' applied to an object of class "c('lmerMod', 'merMod')"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems to work with `effects_3.0-1` and `lme4_1.1-7`

Comment: Thanks for checking, I've just re-installed both packages and now it works... I probably had an old version of the packages